# can we keep/install two versions of azcopy in the windows system

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azcopy

**Current Version of azcopy installed**:

```
>azcopy --version
azcopy version 10.23.0
```

I'm creating the SAS for all the services provided in Storage account to copy between the storage accounts.
While creating for the table service, I got the following error:

`azcopy copy "table_sas_url+token" "destination_table_sas_url+token" --recursive=true`

**Error Message**:

```
INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: 'https://srcstorage.table.core.windows.net/
?se=2024-03-03T14%3A02%3A28Z&sig=-REDACTED-&sp=rwdlacu&spr=https&srt=sco&ss=t&st=2024-03-03T06%3A02%3A28Z&sv=2022-11-02' of type Local, and Destination: 'https://deststorage.table.core.windows.net/?se=2024-03-03T14%3A03%3A06Z&sig=-REDACTED-&sp=rwdlacu&spr=https&srt=sco&ss=t
&st=2024-03-03T06%3A03%3A06Z&sv=2022-11-02' of type Local
INFO: Based on the parameters supplied, a valid source-destination combination could 
not automatically be found. Please check the parameters you supplied.  
If they are correct, please specify an exact source and destination type using the 
--from-to switch. Specified to nudge AzCopy when resource detection may not work (e.g. piping/emulator/azure stack); Valid FromTo are pairs of Source-Destination words (e.g. BlobLocal, BlobBlob) that specify the source and destination resource types. 
All valid FromTos are: BlobBlob, BlobBlobFS, BlobFSBlob, BlobFSBlobFS, BlobFSFile, BlobFSLocal, BlobFile, BlobLocal, BlobPipe, FileBlob, FileBlobFS, FileFile, FileLocal, FilePipe, GCPBlob, LocalBlob, LocalBlobFS, LocalFile, PipeBlob, PipeFile, S3Blob

failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination 
could not be identified, or is currently not supported
```

Later in googling, I come to know that the latest version of azcopy is not supported to table storage service. To perform any copy commands on table service, microsoft recommended to use older version **7.3**

**Can we keep the two versions of azcopy or it is better to go for another solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can we keep the two versions of azcopy or it is better to go for another solution?**

Instead of using AzCopy commands for copying or moving data to Azure Storage, you can use Azure Storage Explorer, which provides a graphical user interface (GUI) and works similarly to AzCopy but with a better GUI interface.

To copy a table from one storage account to another in Microsoft Azure storage Explorer, follow these steps:

1. Sign in to Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer using your Azure credentials.
2. Navigate to the storage account (**`venkat678`**) -> table (**`aztable`**) -> Copy Table.

**Explorer:**
[image]

3. Go to the other storage account (**`venkat789`**) -> Table -> Paste Table.

[image]

This process copies the table from one storage account to another.

**Explorer:**
[image]

Alternatively, you can use Azure Data Factory to copy an Azure table from one storage account to another.

**Reference:**

[Copying Azure Table Storage using Azure Data Factory (ADF) - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/copying-azure-table-storage-using-azure-data-factory-adf/ba-p/3062401)

**Update:**

If you need to copy multiple tables you can use version **azcopy v7.3** with commands.

> Can we keep two versions in the system of that **`azcopy`** module?

Yes, you can use the two **`azcopy`** version use this [link](https://devcodef1.com/news/1162899/installing-two-azcopy-versions#:%7E:text=To%20keep%20two%20versions%20of%20AzCopy%20on%20your,newer%20AzCopy%20folder%20in%20the%20PATH.%20More%20items).

Comment: I Know this ADF Solution where we can copy multiple or all tables at a time but in AzCopy I have asked the question related to versions installing not the alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, If you need to copy multiple tables you can degrade your version `azcopy v7.3` and you can use the azcopy commands.

Comment: Can we keep two versions in the system of that azcopy module?

Comment: Yes, check this link https://devcodef1.com/news/1162899/installing-two-azcopy-versions#:~:text=To%20keep%20two%20versions%20of%20AzCopy%20on%20your,newer%20AzCopy%20folder%20in%20the%20PATH.%20More%20items

Comment: could you please include this link in the answer

Comment: Updated, hope this address your issue.